# Antlr - multiple lexer imports

Tags: antlr3

I am trying to build a combined Antlr grammar that has multiple lexer imports. But, this is not working.
I have two lexer files that is being imported in the combined grammar file. But Im getting this error :error(103):parser rule a not allowed in lexer.

```
 lexer grammar LSub ;

    SPACE : ' ' ;

    lexer grammar L ;

    LETTER : 'a'..'z' ;
    // SPACE : ' ' ;
    NUMBER : '0'..'9' ;


    parser grammar P1 ;

    letter : LETTER ;
    spaces : SPACE+ ;


    grammar C ;
    import L, LSub, P1 ;

    stuff : ( letters spaces )+ ;

    LETTER : 'a'..'z' ;
```

Also, if I try it the two levels of lexer import i.e suppose if I have two lexers L1 and L2, & L2 imports L1 and in the combined grammar if I have imported L2. Then, in the Test Class I get nullpointerexception.

```
lexer grammar LSub ;

SPACE : ' ' ;
lexer grammar L ;

import LSub;

LETTER : 'a'..'z' ;
// SPACE : ' ' ;
NUMBER : '0'..'9' ;


parser grammar P1 ;

letter : LETTER ;
spaces : SPACE+ ;

parser grammar P2 ;
import P1 ;

letters : letter+ ;

grammar C ;
import L, P2 ;

stuff : ( letters spaces )+ ;

LETTER : 'a'..'z' ;
```

Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: Can you post some code that is a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple lexer are not allowed in any parser file. this is a draw back in antlr 3.5. Try importing LSub in L, then L in P1 . you may get .